# xDebug don't work with Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

i'm trying to debug a php project with Netbeans using xDebug but when i start the debug session, also if appear "xdebug is running", breakpoints don't work.

I'm using Netbeans 8.1, XAMPP 3.2.2 and PHP 5.6.
The O.S. is Windows 10.

I searched all day on google but none solution worked.
Here is my php.ini relative to xdebug.
All rows relative to Zend has been commented.

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.0-5.6-vc11.dll
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.0.2
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english :)